# How can I render <script> tags in Contentful RichText

Tags: reactjs, contentful, richtext

I'm having an Contentful blog and would like to know how I can render html  tags in the Contentful RichText field. I'm using the Richtext field as Body for my blog posts. I would like to render between the text some  tags.

When I include my  tag it doesn't render it.

This is how I render the Richtext field in in Gatsby right now:

```
import { documentToReactComponents } from "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer"

{documentToReactComponents(
  body.json,
  options
)}
```

Can I add some sort of HTML renderer to make my  tag work?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: I just saw that Richtext cant render HTML, is there a work around?